# Javascript on load external html files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 external html file (header and footer),

that I load with this code:

```
<div id="header-div"></div>

<div id="footer-div"></div>

$(function () {
    $("#header-div").load("/AfekDent/header.html");
    $("#footer-div").load("/AfekDent/footer.html");
});
```

the header file include javascript code that isn't working..

```
function switchClass(i) {
    var lis = $('#home-news > div');
    lis.eq(i).removeClass('home_header_on');
    lis.eq(i).removeClass('home_header_out');
    lis.eq(i = '++i' % lis.length).addClass('home_header_on');
    lis.eq(i = '++i' % lis.length).addClass('home_header_out');
    setTimeout(function () {
        switchClass(i);
    }, 3500);
}

$(window).load(function () {
    switchClass(-1);
});
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Did you wrap your script in`<script>` tags? Can you give us a complete exanple of the header and footer, please?

Comment: no, the scripts are in an external .js file.

Comment: Your post's title: Javascript on load **external html files**. That's what I was asking for. An external HTML file ends with an extension of `.html` or `.htm`

Answer (score 1):

The `$(window).load()` event is called on the page load, not when the additional HTML has been loaded.

Comment: Ok, so what trigger indicate all elements are loaded (includ the elment in the header files)?

Comment: There isn't one that does what you're asking, at least not directly. The `.load()` method does allow for a callback function, though, so you could track yourself when each of your additional html files is complete and call whatever logic you want when they're both done.